# Is there a way to automatically remove symbol inside Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm currently doing some daily routine configuration, the source file is automatically convert from .csv to .dat . Therefore the .dat files will contain a lot of unwanted symbol which I have to manually remove it. My question is whether there is a way to remove it automatically?

This is the scenario:

Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Don'tRemoveThesePipe|||Don'tRemoveThisPipe||Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe||||||||||||||||||||
Don'tRemoveThesePipe|||Don'tRemoveThisPipe||Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

I've tried using the expression .+(/|) but it will remove all the pipe symbol which is not what I want.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bi4jOtLpRxvkrWvavr1lEMqZI8vKxHOB

I expect the result to be like this:

Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe
Don'tRemoveThesePipe|||Don'tRemoveThisPipe||Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe
Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe
Don'tRemoveThesePipe|||Don'tRemoveThisPipe||Don'tRemoveThisPipe|Don'tRemoveThisPipe|ButRemoveThesePipe

Comment: Maybe match `\|{2,}` and replace with the empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try doing the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find: \|+$
Replace: (leave empty)
```

This should trim off any number of trailing pipes at the end of each line.

### Demo